# Why can't I create a thread in a Boost.Test test case?

Tags: c++, multithreading, unit-testing, boost

I have defined the following very simple test case:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE thread_test_module
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <thread>

void do_nothing() {}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE ( boost_thread_test )
{
    std::thread t(do_nothing);
    t.join();
}
```

When it runs, I get the following error:

```
unknown location(0): fatal error in "boost_thread_test": std::runtime_error: Operation not permitted
```

According to [this post](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Is-boost-test-thread-safe-td3471644.html), it appears that this should work. Why not?

- Compiler: GCC 4.6.3
- Boost: 1.55.0

Comment: Creating threads works just fine in boost unit test cases: [live coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2e5bad368bc7c5b). What is your platform?

Comment: Wondering why this received a down vote. Straight-forward question, complete example, error message is there. I wish people would say *why* they down vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to link with the `pthread` library, by adding `-lpthread` to my linker command line.